# CSS transform:scale(2) + position:absolute + right:0px is not working

Tags: css, transform

I have noticed that `right:0px` is positioning an element incorrectly. `transform:scale` doesn't recalculate the element width.

Is there a way to properly stick this element to the right side?

HTML:

```
<div id="stick_me">
    blah blah blah<br />
    blah blah blah<br />
    blah blah blah<br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#stick_me {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(3);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: show us the css code...

Comment: that's not really helpful to answer....

Comment: Whatever, i have updated the main post. I don't care about reputation :D So if you can't imagine 3 css properties in the mind, that confuses me a bit, i'm in the right place of not :D

Comment: Context is always helpful

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to use the `transform-origin` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property set to `top right`. As you are positioning the element to the top and right, you need it to scale from there, i.e. down and to the left.

```
#stick_me {
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:scale(3);
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  transform-origin:top right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nobloss/ff3h5u65/)

Comment: Thank you mate. Didn't knew about transform-origin.

Comment: For most transforms it's 50% 50% (the middle) by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add this In your css:

```
-ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
```

Full code:

```
#stick_me {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:scale(3);
    -ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/rLa0d3az/1/)**